# Remove double quotes from script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to strip some double quotes out of the code below but only at certain points. The code is saved on my Unix box in a .psql script which I'm trying to manipulate from the command line. I've tried a few sed commands but I'm struggling to isolate the parts I want and keep losing all the quotes. What I'm trying to do is:

1 - leave all the double quotes in tact up to the "AS SELECT" part
of the CREATE statement. Everything in the brackets and prior needs
to keep quotes.

2 - After the "AS SELECT" part of the CREATE statement, I want to strip out quotes up to the ";" at the end of the CREATE statement including the WHERE clause.

3 - there are a few COMMENT statements below also, I only want to remove any quotes before the "IS E' " part of the statement. Anything after this is fine.

4 - Below is an example of my code and how it looked after my
manual fixes. Any help to automate this and save my little fingers
would be great!

## **My Code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "devices_loomis" ("id", "key", "signal", "status", "active", "local", "tep", "os_name", "mod_name", "mtime", "muser", "ctime", "cuser", "remark") AS SELECT  "d".ID, "d".KEY, "d".SIGNAL, "d".STATUS, "d".ACTIVE, "d".LOCAL, "d".TEP, "d".OS_NAME, "d".MOD_NAME, "d".MTIME, "d".MUSER, "d".CTIME, "d".CUSER, "d".REMARK  FROM DEVICES d, ATTRIBUTES a WHERE "d".ID = "a".DEV_ID AND "a".TOK_NAME='Responsible' AND "a".VALUE = 'Loomis';

COMMENT ON VIEW "DEVICES_LOOMIS"  IS E'View of Loomis devices.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "DEVICES_LOOMIS".ACTIVE IS E'Set if device "is" active.';
```

These are the sed commands I've been playing with but they seem to be overwriting each other.

```
sed '/COMMENT ON VIEW/s/"\(.*\)".*IS/\1 IS/g' it.text
sed '/COMMENT ON COLUMN/s/"\(.*\)".\(.*\).*IS/\1.\2 IS/g' it.text
sed '/CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW/s/AS SELECT.*"\(.*\)".*FROM/AS SELECT \1 FROM/g' it.text
```

## **After manual fixes:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "devices_loomis" ("id", "key", "signal", "status", "active", "local", "tep", "os_name", "mod_name", "mtime", "muser", "ctime", "cuser", "remark") AS SELECT  d.ID, d.KEY, d.SIGNAL, d.STATUS, d.ACTIVE, d.LOCAL, d.TEP, d.OS_NAME, d.MOD_NAME, d.MTIME, d.MUSER, d.CTIME, d.CUSER, d.REMARK  FROM DEVICES d, ATTRIBUTES a WHERE d.ID = a.DEV_ID AND a.TOK_NAME='Responsible' AND a.VALUE = 'Loomis';

COMMENT ON VIEW DEVICES_LOOMIS  IS E'View of Loomis devices.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN DEVICES_LOOMIS.ACTIVE IS E'Set if device "is" active.';
```

Comment: _I've tried a few sed commands_  .... I don't see any sed or bash code in your posting. How can we discuss problems with your current solution, if you don't reveal what you have done?

Comment: `sed s/DEVICES_LOOMIS/devices_loomis/g` will fix your problem.